# Get the children of a div element

Tags: javascript, dom

I have created a chess board using a table element and I want to get all the divs so I can see it  printed in the console

Since there are 64 squares I want to see them all listed in the the console so I can make an array from it, but what I get instead is `HTMLCollection [div#id, id: div#id]` . How could i get it to console out all the elements in it?

```js
let div = document.getElementsByClassName('board')
div[0].setAttribute('id', 'divid')
let divId = document.getElementById('divid')

var table = document.createElement("div");
table.id = 'id'
let id=0;
for (var i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
  var tr = document.createElement('tr');
  for (var j = 1; j < 9; j++) {
    var td = document.createElement('td');
    id++
    td.id = id
    if (i % 2 == j % 2) {
      td.className = "white";
    } else {
      td.className = "black";
    }
    tr.appendChild(td);
  }

  table.appendChild(tr);
}

divId.appendChild(table)

console.log(divId.children)
```

```html
<div class="board"></div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. I added `let id=0;`

Comment: See updated code. It is pretty complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why div and tr?

This makes more sense.

Also I give the cells the proper chess ID

```js
const hor = "ABCDEFGH";
const pieces = {
  "A1": "rook",
  "A2": "pawn",
  "A7": "pawn",
  "A8": "rook",
  "B1": "knight",
  "B2": "pawn",
  "B7": "pawn",
  "B8": "knight",
  "C1": "bishop",
  "C2": "pawn",
  "C7": "pawn",
  "C8": "bishop",
  "D1": "queen",
  "D2": "pawn",
  "D7": "pawn",
  "D8": "queen",
  "E1": "king",
  "E2": "pawn",
  "E7": "pawn",
  "E8": "king",
  "F1": "bishop",
  "F2": "pawn",
  "F7": "pawn",
  "F8": "bishop",
  "G1": "knight",
  "G2": "pawn",
  "G7": "pawn",
  "G8": "knight",
  "H1": "rook",
  "H2": "pawn",
  "H7": "pawn",
  "H8": "rook"
};

const getPiece = (id, color) => color && pieces[id] ? `<i class="${color==='black'?'fas':'far'} fa-chess-${pieces[id]}" aria-hidden="true">` : '';


const table = document.getElementById("board");
let id = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  let tr = document.createElement('tr');
  let number = document.createElement('th');
  number.textContent = 8 - i;
  tr.appendChild(number)
  for (let j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
    let row = hor[j];
    let cell = 8 - i
    let td = document.createElement('td');
    let id = `${row}${cell}`;
    td.id = id
    td.className = (i % 2 == j % 2) ? "white" : "black";
    let color = ''
    if (cell <= 2) color = "white";
    else if (cell >= 6) color = "black";
    td.innerHTML = getPiece(td.id, color)
    tr.appendChild(td);
  }
  table.appendChild(tr);
}
const arr = table.querySelectorAll('td');

// set A4 to red
document.getElementById('A4').classList.toggle('red');

// set the 16th entry to blue (JS array start at 0)
document.getElementById(arr[15].id).classList.toggle('blue');

// pawn to E4
document.querySelector("#E2 i")?.classList.remove('pawn');
document.querySelector("#E4 i")?.classList.add('pawn');

// console.log(JSON.stringify([...arr].map(cell => cell.id)))
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tbody {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px black;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#board td,
th {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  font-size: 24px;
}



table th {
  background-color: teal
}

.white {
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  /* vertical-align: top; */
}

.black {
  background-color: grey;
  text-align: center;
  /*  vertical-align: top; */
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}


.pawn {

  color: black;
}

.black .pawn::before {
  content: "\f443";
}

.white .pawn::before {
  content: "\f443";
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css" />

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
      <th>D</th>
      <th>E</th>
      <th>F</th>
      <th>G</th>
      <th>H</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="board"></tbody>
</table>
```